# Font size of bibliography page number in toc is inconsistent

Tags: table-of-contents, bibtex, fontsize, page-numbering

This is the last problem standing between me and the university accepting my PhD thesis.

For some reason, the page number of the bibliography entry in the table of contents is larger than any of the other entries and I can't figure out how to change it.

[image: Example of the inconsistent page number sizing in the TOC.]

The document is compiled using a custom thesis.cls file that my university specifies. I believe these are the relevant lines in the document which set the toc options for size of different sections of the toc. I've verified that this section is actually touched during compilation by inserting the `typeout` call and by e.g. changing the spelling of bibliography.

```
\else
    % \typeout{no cap chapter names}
    \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\th@ChapHead{Contents}}
    \renewcommand*{\listfigurename}{\th@ChapHead{Figures}}
    \renewcommand*{\listtablename}{\th@ChapHead{Tables}}
    \renewcommand*{\appendixname}{\th@ChapHead{Appendix}}
    \renewcommand*{\bibname}{\th@ChapHead{Bibliography}}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{\th@ChapHead{Chapter}}
    \newcommand*{\chapternameToC}{
        \normalsize\th@HdFnt Chapter\normalfont}
    \newcommand*{\bibnameToC}{
        \normalsize\th@HdFnt  Bibliography\normalfont}
    \newcommand*{\appendixnameToC}{
        \normalsize\th@HdFnt Appendix\normalfont}
\fi
```

Here is the abbreviated code from the main.tex file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,modernstyle]{thesis}  % Switch to {thesis} for PhD final paper
\begin{document}

\input chapter_introduction.tex
\input chapter_Conclusions.tex
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu\relax

\bibliographystyle{plain}   % or "siam", or "alpha", etc.
\nocite{*}               % list all refs in database, cited or not
\bibliography{bibtex_database}
\appendix
\input appendix_Baseline.tex
\input appendix_AR.tex
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling my documents using sublimetext and the LaTexTools package. 
Does anyone have any insight into how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: the code you are showing doesn't set the style of the page number, only the name.

Comment: If you haven't fiddled with anything and your university requires you to use the particular class file then they should either accept the result or fix the class file. I can't help as you have provided no code that I can run. --- GOM

Comment: The full cls file is about 1200 lines. Is there a way I can provide it that is practical?

Comment: A bare-bones version of the thesis with associated thesis.cls files are available here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/wbhrndgfrrjr